# robot_localization and bag file output

Tags: navigation, roslaunch, rosbag, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
Have anyone tried to run the test1.bag , test2.bag and test3.bag files included in the robot_localization package? Do you have any screen shot for correct output from these bag files and corresponding launch files? I would like to try them and compare the results with mine.

If you have them, could you please share with me?

If you have any other working samples especially (IMU + Raw Odometry), could you please share with me?

Best Regards
Min Latt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268046/robot_localization-and-bag-file-output/) by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-08-04**:
Hello,

If you want more bag file, you can check on [marvhub](https://marvhub.com) , there is a lot of dataset from mit stata center. They contains IMU + Odometry from a pr2, maybe you can use them.

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-08-04**:
Thanks a lot for your support. robot_localization has three bag files. What I want is the corresponding output for these bag files so that I can check whether I am using robot_localization correctly. BTW does the bag file includes the expected output(ground truth) and (IMU + Raw Odometry)?

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-08-04**:
The ground thruth is present according to the description of the set.

I'm not able to use the robot_localization package right now, but if i'm able to use it, I will send you a bag with my result so you can compare (But tomorrow at the earliest)

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-08-04**:
Thanks a lot. I am fine with waiting. "Good things come to those who wait"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-04**:
Is this a duplicate of #q268047?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After not be able to use the package correctly (I need to understand EKF), I found the test files for robot_localization :

- [test1.bag](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/test/test_ekf_localization_node_bag1.test)
- [test2.bag](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/test/test_ekf_localization_node_bag2.test)
- [test3.bag](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/test/test_ekf_localization_node_bag3.test)

You have 2 way of launching these files (both require you to clone and compile [the package on github](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/), these file are not present with apt-get):

### Quick method :

Launch these file like a normal .launch file :

`roslaunch < your robot_localization package path >/test/test_ekf_localization_node_bag1.test`

Then subscribe to the **/odometry/filtered** topic and look at the last message, the position should be nearby equal to the position defined at the end of the file. Example for bag1 :

```
      <param name="final_x" value="-40.0454"/>
      <param name="final_y" value="-76.9988"/>
      <param name="final_z" value="-2.6974"/>
      <param name="tolerance" value="1.0452"/>
```

I recorded the 3 results for EKF in bag files :

- [test1_result.bag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BRMr7Z9cxfZTJWeGJWRldBXzQ/view?usp=sharing)
- [test2_result.bag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BRMr7Z9cxfUzFMNFY1a3U1aEU/view?usp=sharing)
- [test3_result.bag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BRMr7Z9cxfTFVZdDFQRnprNGc/view?usp=sharing)

### With rostest

Robot_localization come with a script to test the 2 nodes (ekf and ukf) with the 3 bag files.

But this is for the default parameters, if you want to test your own parameters, change them at the begining of the *.test files and run the stats recorder. If the output fail, you are probably doing something wrong.

To run the stats recorder, go to robot_localization/test/ and run `./record_all_stats.sh <output_path>` (don't forget the output_path) , it will output :

> < output_path >/ekf(1,2,3).txt

and  :

> < output_path >/ukf(1,2,3).txt.

It will run 30 times each node for each bag file (so it will take a very long time...) and try to ouput statistic based on your parameters (try only. If you look at the script, it seem to run the tests 30 times only)

---

Have fun !

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-08-07**:
Hi lmathieu,
Thanks a lot for your time and great effort. I will try with these bag files. Hopefully it works for me as well.

Thanks again.

Best Regards

Min Latt